# Access to a remote Mysql server (wamp on windows) from Raspberry Pi with (MysqlConnector) in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, raspberry-pi, connection, wamp

I have a problem to establish the link between my raspberry pi and my SQL server hosted on my computer.

I'm coding with C# on the raspberry pi and I'm using MysqlConnector to open a connection. I have correctly made my wamp online, thus with the browser, I can see my wamp homepage on my raspberry. I have correctly entered all the credentials in the connection string: the hostname is my computer IP address: 192.168.1.2 and the user I'm using to get connected have all privileges granted.

When I execute my c# code, the error 1042 occurred, which correspond to a failure in the hostname resolution. Therefore I added an entry in my host file on my raspberry: `"192.168.1.2 name_of_my_computer"` and then I use in my program `"name_of_my_computer"` as the hostname of my remote sqlServer, but the error still occurs.

Dou you have any ideas to make it work? Thank you.